# internet explorer adding insufficient br to my code

Tags: jquery, css

essentially what is rendered on my site is a few rows of divs that are styled to be the same size through css.. in firefox, chrome, and safari the site renders fine and allows 10 x 10 sets of the rows to appear as a larger cube (each row of 10 broken by a br tag)

any clue as to where I would begin to "fix" this? I am half tempted to completely alienate ie users though...

http://wet-monkey.com/rpgGame is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed you haven't included a Doctype on your web page, have you tried adding one? This may be the cause.

The alternative could be the `line-height` attribute - try setting that to 0px:

```
line-height:0px;
```

Comment: I just added <!DOCTYPE Html>, made the line-height 100% for all the div classes, and rearranged the doctype, html and head tags, even added a title so it would validate properly (which it does), yet it still looks bad in ie.

Comment: @g00ch I've noticed the float:left; applied to .darkStone seems to be causing it to look really bad - if you turn that off it looks the same in all the browsers - however it causes a small gap between each row, so something else needs to be changed. Weird.

Comment: hmm, ill have to try killing the float left part then,

Comment: @g00ch There's a <br> in between each line causing the gap - have you tried replacing these <br> tags with <br /> (or even removing it if it's unneeded)

Comment: I have in the past, thing is <br> is html, and <br /> is xhtml last I checked, I was having the same rendering issue with ie which is why I actually went with the <br> v the <br/> initially.

Comment: @g00ch You're correct. I'm trying to find out what's causing the gap between blocks as there doesn't seem to be any padding/margins affecting it :s

Comment: yeah, I even tried adding margin 0, padding 0 to the various div classes, the float left made it look decent, I am thinking of making an ie version that looks like its current state with a message "use a real browser"

Comment: ok, aparently if I set the line-height attribute to 0px it works, I even tried adding it to the br tag which didn't work

Comment: @g00ch Ah, that's weird, I tried deleting the line-height but it didn't do anything, funny how 0px works! glad you found the solution anyway!

Comment: @g00ch It works in IE9 and IE8 for me, that should be good enough I'd have thought :)

Comment: yeah, im not exactly targeting the site to old school buisnesses afraid to change away from ie 6 so..

Comment: @g00ch Thankfully most of them are finally moving up to IE8 (including my one, thank God) it's frustrating but at least you're targetting the large majority with chrome, firefox and ie8+

Comment: it works on opera in turbo mode which is weird, I guess I could add a popup later to tell em to use turbo mode

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the `line-height` attribute; set it to 100%. Depending on the version of IE and your `doctype`, it may not read correctly.